# GetJSON returns data asyncronously

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I am using this code to get data from DataBase

```
    var ourData ='';
    $.getJSON('getGaleri.php',function(data){
        ourData =data;

    });
    //alert('loading');


    });
    html = html + '</ul></div></div>';
    setTimeout(function(){
$.each(ourData, function(i, item) {
        html = html +"<li class='modern konserler'><a href='"+path+ourData[i].resim_banner+"' rel='bookmark' class='fancybox'><img src='"+path+ourData[i].resim_banner+"' alt='ThemeMarket' /><div><span></span></div></a></li>";
        $('#content').html(html);
    }, 4000);
```

to get it working I need to uncomment the fourth line `alert()` and get `ourData` filled with data,
if I didn't comment it, it will give nothing, `ourData` will be empty string, I thought using `setTimeout` could help but it didn't,

How to fix it so I don't need `alert()` to get data filled in `ourData` variable

Comment: Well yes, but more accurately, getJSON returns data asynchronously.

Comment: you can try like this $.getJSON('getGaleri.php',function(data){
            ourData =data;
            $.each(ourData, function(i, item) { 
                html = html +""; 
            }); 
            html = html + '</ul></div></div>';
        });

or try inside success callbacks

Answer (score 0):

That's because `alert` blocks the thread long enough for the `getJSON` to complete, after alert `ourData` has been populated. Use your `each` inside the callback:

```
$.getJSON('getGaleri.php',function(data){

    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        html = html +"<li class='modern konserler'><a href='"+path+data[i].resim_banner+"' rel='bookmark' class='fancybox'><img src='"+path+data[i].resim_banner+"' alt='ThemeMarket' /><div><span></span></div></a></li>";

    });

});
```

Comment: Any errors? Have you used `data[i]` or `ourData[i]` inside the callback?

Comment: used data[i] but it is still the same, no data retruned

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` inside your `$.getJSON('getGaleri.php',function(data){` to make sure you're getting data. Also make sure it's `$.each(data` not `$.each(ourData`. This code should work if you're getting the correct data from the server.

Comment: added it, the data is fetched and then printed in the console